# How to rename a systemd service without affecting the process (no stop/restart)

Tags: systemd

There are multiple reasons to have to rename a systemd service in production. For example:

- to better differentiate it from a new one
- because your boss ordered it
- because of legacy scripts
- ...

Assuming a new generic service created in `/etc/systemd/system/foo.service` and enabled and started as follow: [1]

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable --now foo
```

Then, you may want to rename it from `foo.service` to `bar.service` without impacting the related process in any way.

In normal circumstances you can just do something like this:

```
mv foo.service bar.service
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl disable foo
systemctl enable  bar
```

Then you obtain:

- `systemctl status foo`: `running` `not-found` `disabled`
- `systemctl status bar`: `not-running` `enabled`

So you may want to fix with:

```
systemctl stop  foo
systemctl start bar
```

Or with a reboot. However in production environments this is not feasible since you don't want to stop the application for such change. Additionally, reboots are scheduled after months or years. At the same time, it's risky to keep for a long time a stopped service like `bar` that should not be started by mistake before stopping the not-found running `foo`.

In short. What approach would you use to rename a systemd service in production?

The ideal condition would be to have the two services backward compatible. Thus, stopping `foo` also stops `bar` and vice versa.

---

- [1] https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/chap-managing_services_with_systemd#sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_File_Create
- [2] https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There may be some better method that I am unaware of, but this comes to mind as a workaround that mostly gets you what you need until you have the chance to restart the service:

1. Create a symlink with the desired new name which points to the existing service file (and `systemctl daemon-reload`).
   Systemd [treats symlinks to units as aliases](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) instead of separate units, meaning that both names will now refer to the same unit (same status, same everything).
2. Plan to actually replace the service during your next maintenance window.